# fatal: Application timed out after 00:10:00.3431942

Tags: python, docker, flask, subprocess, popen

Packaged a MONAI Deploy app following the instructions [here](https://docs.monai.io/projects/monai-deploy-app-sdk/en/0.5.1/developing_with_sdk/packaging_app.html). Used the output docker image (MAP) as base image to create a new docker image using a Dockerfile. The Dockerfile is doing nothing much except that I have created a `inference.py` file which uses [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) to expose an endpoint using POST method on 8080 port. When this endpoint is hit, it triggers the MONAI App Package (MAP) using Python's `subprocess` to trigger the command, exactly as shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). Using port forwarding the 8080 port is exposed to the host system.

```
docker run -it --network host -p 8080:8080 <image_id>
```

Using cURL, the Flask endpoint is hit from the host system. After about 10 minutes the application abruptly stops running throwing only 1 line of error "fatal: Application timed out after 00:10:00.3431942". No tracebacks and no entering into try-except blocks which I had written. Since only this 1 line is thrown I am not even sure where it failed, which component failed and why.

At this point of time, I am not sure if the source of the error is Python, subprocess, Flask, Docker, MONAI or something else.
How to debug this issue?
Has anybody been through this issue? If yes, how did you fix this? Any other pointers?